# Cant connect to Nexus Repository Manager with Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, nexus3

I want to upload my generated artifacts (.zip) to my Nexus Repository Manager (nexus3).
Therefore I downloadede the `Nexus Repository Manager Plugin`for my Jenkins instance.
With `confige System -> Nexus Repository Manager Servers` I am able to establish and verify a connection to my NRM.

But after hitting `Test connection` I receive the following error:

```
    Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed
com.sonatype.nexus.api.dr: Unauthorized

    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.ds.handleResponse(SourceFile:51)

    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:223)

    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:165)

    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.dn.a(SourceFile:84)

Caused: com.sonatype.nexus.api.exception.RepositoryManagerException: Get repositories was unsuccessful (401 response from server)

    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.dn.a(SourceFile:106)

    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.dn.a(SourceFile:87)

    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.dm.getRepositories(SourceFile:123)

    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.repository.v3.RepositoryManagerV3Client$getRepositories.call(Unknown Source)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)

    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.util.Nxrm3Util.getApplicableRepositories(Nxrm3Util.groovy:49)

    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.util.Nxrm3Util$getApplicableRepositories.callStatic(Unknown Source)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:222)

    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.config.Nxrm3Configuration$DescriptorImpl.doVerifyCredentials(Nxrm3Configuration.groovy:79)

    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)

    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)

    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)

    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:114)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)

    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:64)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)

    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)

    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)

    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)

    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)

    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know that my url is valid and the credentials I use to login have admin rights on my NRM instance.

EDIT: now I am confused. If I give no credentials and test the connection everything works....